# laravel - 'Auth' is not working in cron schedule

Tags: laravel

I have created a cron job in the 'commands' files. and I want to get the id of the user using **Auth::user()->id** but I am getting the error. Where am I missing?

**My error:**

Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

**My controller**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

protected $signature = 'orders:minute';

public function handle()
    {
        $id = Auth::user()->id;
    }
```

**Kernel.php**

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('orders:minute')
    ->everyMinute();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that because a user doesn't run the scheduled command, so `Auth::user()` object will always be `null`.

To fix this, you can save User Id in Database and fetch the data on scheduled command execution.

Comment: i have no idea how i can get data with scheduled command execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because a user doesn't run the cron scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

For the use case you're showing you'd have to provide it yourself, for example as a command argument:

```
protected $signature = 'command:Orders {user_id : id of the recipient model}';

public function handle() {
      $user_id = $this->argument('user_id');
      $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
      // other commands
}
```

So executing `php artisan command:SendNotification 1` would act as if user 1 was authenticated.

Comment: I understand that you want me to type the user's id manually, but I don't want that. what i want is to be able to get the id of the authenticated user.

Comment: @322quick1 But, how to get authenticated user without login? It's not possible without a login. and you can't log in to cron.

Comment: @322quick1 there's no request object or authenticated user in the queue. You need to pass the authenticated user to the queue class. Can you explain in a little bit more on what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Cron means to **run something automatically**. You can't do that because a user doesn't run the cron scheduled. You only get **Auth::user()->id** when the user login